# Calculating a double integral on unit circle

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

My question is:
$\iint_\Omega xy\,dx\,dy$ where $\Omega$ is the first quadrant bounded by $x^2+y^2=1$

I've managed to integrate normally to give $\frac{x^2y^2}{2}+C+Cy$

How would I then apply the bounds of the integral?

Comment: Multivariate integrals don't have "antiderivatives". That is a purely $1$D (and vector fields, too, when you talk about conservativeness) notion, so the expression you have is meaningless.

Comment: The region is shouting "polar coordinates" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can integrate "normally" without first applying the bounds, since the bounds of the inter integral depend on the outer variable of integration.

Note that here, since you are in the first quadrant, both $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$, so we can solve for either. Let's pick $y$:
$$
y^2 = 1 - x^2 \text{ with } x,y \ge 0 \implies y = \sqrt{1-x^2},
$$
so we have $0 \le y \le \sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $0 \le x \le 1$.

Can you now apply those bounds and integrate correctly?

---

**UPDATE**
So we have
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^1 \int_0^\sqrt{1-x^2} xy dydx
 &= \frac12 \int_0^1 x \left(1-x^2\right)dx \\
 &= \frac{1}{-4} \int_0^1 (-2)x \left(1-x^2\right)dx \\
 &= \frac{-1}{8} \left(1-x^2\right)^2 \\
 &= \frac18.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thanks, I believe I got the my answer as $\frac{1}{8}$, could you please confirm this if possible?

Comment: @anamigo26 please see update

Answer (score 0):

In first quadrant you have set
$$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{}
0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \\
0 \leqslant y \leqslant \sqrt{1-x^2}
\end{array}\right\rbrace
$$
So integral will be
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$
More easy it looks for so called polar coordinates
$$\begin{cases}
x=r \cos \phi \\
y= r \sin \phi
\end{cases}
$$
Area transfer to
$$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{}
0 \leqslant \phi \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2} \\
0 \leqslant r \leqslant 1
\end{array}\right\rbrace
$$
and integral
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_{0}^{1}rf(r \cos \phi,r \sin \phi)\,d\phi,dr$$

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^1( \sin \theta \cos \theta\;d\theta) (\;r\;dr \;) $$

separate integration..

$$\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot \dfrac{-\cos \theta}{2}|_0^{\pi/2} \quad= \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot -\dfrac12 \cdot -2=\dfrac{1}{3} $$